# Looking for greasemonkey script(s) to format numbers (only) in different font

Tags: script, fonts, format, greasemonkey

I love to see numbers in Georgia font and would love to see them auto-formatted into that font! If you know such tools, please share!

ps. I want just numbers to be formatted while other texts remain as-is while surfing the web.

Comment: That would ruin the internet.. :|

Comment: @Lipis: It is my personal interest and I don't see why the Internet is ruined by my sole me!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is actually not trivial to accomplish using JavaScript, so I'm not quite sure if anyone out there has done it already. However, since creating one would be an interesting exercise in looking at the inner workings of the DOM, I gave it a shot at creating one:

> ### [All Numbers in Georgia](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/93665)
>
> **Script Summary:** All your numbers are belong to Georgia!
>
> **[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/93665.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/93665)**
>
> **Before:**
>
> [image]
>
> **After:**
>
> [image]

For those of you who are crazy enough to try writing something like this, [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Oy, no picture of before/after? @YiJiang I'm losing my confidence in you! :p

Comment: @drachenstern, jiang: Me too ^_^! I installed it though, giving my fate to you :D

Comment: @Jiang: The number in Google Contact is not formatted by the script. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Nam If you're talking about the numbers in the form elements when you are editing the contact details, then I'm sorry, having two different font there is impossible. If you're not talking about that, then I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: @Jiang: New problem - cannot open Google Image Search any more :)

Comment: @Jiang: [When opening one specific contact] It is about the phone number displayed in Google Contact Jiang. It looks like a label but when mouse hovered, it turns into a textbox. Can you explain why it is impossible to have two fonts for a editbox?

Comment: @Nam Because... well, that's how HTML form elements work - `input` elements like the search box up there, as well as `textarea` element like the comment textbox, doesn't allow for other elements to be placed in them, which is what the script is doing to get the numbers to be styled in a different font, so the fonts for all form elements are uniform. As to the Google Image problem, well I'm sorry - the JavaScript error is buried deep inside a ton of minified JavaScript, making it impossible debug. You can add an exclusion rule to sites that don't work with the script

Comment: @Jiang I'm using Chrome, how can I toogle on/off the script? And one more, how can I add exception?

Comment: @Nam Userscripts are installed as extensions in Chrome, so you can disable it from there. Apparently there's no way the user can add exclusion rules himself in Chrome, unlike what Greasemonkey on Firefox does, but I've added the rules to the script myself. Just uninstall and reinstall the script.

Comment: @Jiang I have re-install the extension but the problem remain as-is :D

Comment: @Jiang I cannot send mail using mail.google.com for now - not sure you if it was caused by the script. Do you have the same problem?