# A script for Violent Monkey to revert Reddit's UI?

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I seem to ask these sorts of questions a lot, so, in short, Reddit recently got uglier for some reason like so many sites and services are doing these days and I'd like to change it back. Is there a script for Violent Monkey/Tamper Monkey/Grease Monkey that can change Reddit back to the older UI, not the old.reddit UI but the slightly older one they had just before putting in that left sidebar? Or even just the one from last year?

I've got a script that automatically switches Reddit to the old.reddit UI

```
function test(url){
    return !!url.match(/^(|http(s?):\/\/)(|www.)reddit.com(\/.*|$)/gim);
}

function getNewPagePlease(url){
    return 'https://old.reddit.com' + url.split('reddit.com').pop();
}

function fixRedditStuff(){
    var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.links, 0);
    links.filter(function(link){
        if(test(link.href)){
            var greatNewLink = getNewPagePlease(link.href);
            if(link.hasAttribute('data-outbound-url')) link.setAttribute('data-outbound-url', greatNewLink);
            link.setAttribute('href', greatNewLink);
        }
    });
}

if(test(window.location.href)){window.location.assign(getNewPagePlease(window.location.href));}

window.onload = fixRedditStuff;
setInterval(fixRedditStuff, 50);
```

and have already attempted modifying it to no avail.

Comment: "Product" recommendations are off-topic on Super User.

Comment: @DanielB I'm not asking for a product. Or a recommendation. Just a solution to a problem.

Comment: Here are similar questions regarding finding a script [Where can I find an updated Google filter Greasmonkey script?](https://superuser.com/q/147360/152004) ,  [Looking for greasemonkey script(s) to format numbers (only) in different font](https://superuser.com/q/226508/152004) both from 2010. Another, in this case from the OP, from 2021 : [A script for Violentmonkey to automatically add something to the end of all wikia URLs?](https://superuser.com/q/1660456/152004)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add more popular tags, i.e. one for the web browser that you are using, update it regarding what you said in a comment to my answer and more details about how you found the new layout , if this is in the homepage or in a subreddit.

Comment: If you are not asking for software recommendation, edit your question to remove this clear request which is there in the middle of your first paragraph. The remainder of the question is asking for help writing a script but you don't show us what you've tried, nor do you explain precisely what has changed in the site that you wish to revert or change.

Answer (score 0):

According to (in order of how I found them skimming the results that `https://www.google.com/search?q=old+reddit+layout` returned to me)

- https://www.itgeared.com/how-to-go-back-to-old-reddit-layout/, dated October 19, 2022,
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit
- https://techindroid.com/new-reddit-design-sucks-switch-back-to-old-reddit/, dated October 20, 2020
- and many others,

in order to use the old Reddit layout in your web browser go to https://old.reddit.com.

Considering the above there is no need to use a userscript.

Here how it looks using Chrome

[image: https://old.reddit.com]

Here how https://reddit.com looks

[image: https://reddit.com]

Comment: I wasn't asking about using old.reddit, as I mentioned in the question. In the last few weeks reddit's appearance had been changed from what it had looked like even just last year in 2022. I'm not sure if it was a sweeping change or one of those "some people will see the new design we're testing" changes that sites seem to enjoy doing, but it was indeed different from both previous designs. However, it seems reddit themselves have now reverted the site to the previous design I was looking for a script to restore so I assume they're either done testing and/or realized it was a bad idea.